# How to create a vanilla UTC time ticker?

Tags: javascript, date

I am working with a sun calculator and need a reference date/time that is NOT affected of timezones or DST changes. How much I am trying, javascript (and the browser, I presume), destroy the smooth run of the sun in the sky. How can I create a date/time that I can step through in minute, hour, day, month steps without this damn DST interfering it? - Zones and localizing is no problem.
The promblem seems to be, that all of my defined UTC dates always do jump into and out of the DST. Only the real sun doesn't.

Some of my unhappy tries here:

```
{   //UTC DATE OVERALL
   myutcdate=new Date(mydate.getUTCFullYear(),mydate.getUTCMonth(),mydate.getUTCDate(),mydate.getUTCHours(),mydate.getUTCMinutes());
   //myutcdate=new Date(mydate.valueOf()-localoffset*60*60*1000);
   //var utcoffset=myutcdate.getTimezoneOffset/-60;
   //if(mydate.isDST() && !myutcdate.isDST())myutcdate.setHours(myutcdate.getHours()+1);
   //if(myutcdate.isDST())myutcdate.setHours(myutcdate.getHours()-1);
   //myutcdate= new Date(mydate.getUTCFullYear(),mydate.getUTCMonth(),mydate.getUTCDate(),mydate.getUTCHours(),mydate.getUTCMinutes(),);
   //myutcdate= new Date(mydate.toUTCString());
   //myutcdate= new Date(mydate).toISOString();// returns just a sring, not a date, and cannot be converted to a date
   //myutcdate= new Date(mydate.toISOString());//returns plain local time
   //myutc= new Date(mydate.valueOf() - parseInt(localoffset)*60*60*1000 );
   //myutcdate=Date.UTC(myutc.getFullYear(),myutc.getMonth(),myutc.getDate(),myutc.getHours(),myutc.getMinutes());
   //myutcdate= new Date(myutcdate);
   //document.getElementById('utcdate').innerHTML=myutcdate;//.toSimpleIso(); //myutcdate with own format
   //document.getElementById('utcdate').innerHTML=myutcdate.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+String(myutcdate.getUTCMonth()+1)+"-"+myutcdate.getUTCDate()+" "+myutcdate.getUTCHours()+":"+myutcdate.getUTCMinutes();//.toSimpleIso(); //Yields to reducing double the zone of source date
   //document.getElementById('utcdate').innerHTML=myutcdate.getFullYear()+"-"+String(myutcdate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+myutcdate.getDate()+" "+myutcdate.getHours()+":"+myutcdate.getMinutes();//.toSimpleIso(); //myutcdate with own format
   document.getElementById('utcdate').innerHTML=mydate.toISOString();
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: I suggest you check the libraries mentioned here: https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs however this won't be vanilla. Anyway, it is not clear to me what exactly yo do wrong, as UTC has no DST correction, only local time can have.

Comment: Any date that I create jumps into DST and out when passing the switch date and time, no matter how I define it. As UTC defined they just start with zero zone, but add one hour this year at March 31, 03:00 to 04:00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Date constructor assumes local, to get UTC, use *Date.UTC* to generate the time value, e.g.

```
// Instead of 
new Date(mydate.getUTCFullYear(), ...)

// Use
new Date(Date.UTC(mydate.getUTCFullYear(),...))
//-------^^^^^^^^
```

Then use UTC methods for everything.

```js
 
var d = new Date();
// Copy date using UTC values
var c = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate(), d.getUTCHours(), d.getUTCMinutes(), d.getUTCSeconds(), d.getUTCMilliseconds()));

console.log(d.toISOString());
console.log(c.toISOString());
```

Comment: Thank you, that's it! Now my sun glides smoothly over the sky despite of earthly (foolish) clock adjustments. How come I didn't find it myself? Different libraries were offered to every query, but not this native solution. This I call vanilla. *Hug*